# Dual LED Configuration

Tags: led, components, output, configuration, dual

I'm looking for a dual color red/green LED that is not common-anode, not common-cathode, but common anode-cathode (anode of one LED shares a pin with the cathode of the other LED). Can anyone list a manufacturer and part number of a through-hole LED with this type of configuration?  It seems like this should exist, because you could control which LED turns on with a single digital output and two resistors. Is there a special name for this type of configuration? I'm not interested in circuits that use extra diodes or transistors to allow a common-anode or common-cathode dual LED to be controlled with a single digital output. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Dual Red/Green 3-pin LED]

Comment: two indicators are redundant. Try BIVAR. I can't imagine anyone else wanting to make this.  Dual LEDS are either Common Cathode (popular) or Common Anode or separate  4p . No specs for colour,  brightness, shape ,size SMT or THT.   I  expect none to be found

Comment: You can get even simpler than your idea - an LED that has two emitters connected in parallel but reversed. You only need one resistor and two GPIO pins then.  Here's an example: https://www.rapidonline.com/kingbright-l-57egw-5mm-red-green-led-bi-colour-55-0172

Comment: I've never seen one. If you need sufficient quantity and are willing to pay the appropriate price, one can probably be manufactured. I doubt there's a worthwhile market for such a part.

Comment: That would require the digital output to both source and sink LED current.  That current is enormous by digital signaling standards, and I'm not sure of any digital output which would do that. Can you name a chip you would drive it with?

Comment: Use a bi color smd led plus a small adapter pcb. Or epoxy to combine two thru hole leds. Or a light pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a 4-pin (most likely only SMT) dual red/green LED and make either of the two possible anode-cathode connections yourself. Or connect them as common anode or common cathode.

There are many such products which you can find with a simple search. I won't bother copying typical specs and link here. You can buy use light pipes if you need to move the light somewhere.